# Stranger Math Things

Tags: mathematics, pattern, lateral-thinking

How does this work?:

$$\begin{array}\
&2+3 = 52 \\
&3 \times 2 = 51 \\
&2^3 =  53\\
&\frac{3}2 = 51.52 \\
    \end{array}
$$
Hint:

> The  "5" in the first position of the answers is not "fixed," per se, yet, coincidentally, I can't conceive of an answer that would *not* start with 5.

More equations:

> 7 x 2 = 56
>  9 + 8 = 57
>  3 - 2 = 51
>  3 - 1 = 51

Comment: Related: [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4574334/)

Comment: Do those 'formulas' each stand by themselves or do they inter-relate in some manner that is crucial to the solution?

Comment: my answer would be :things i've never seen.

Comment: Apple mathematics? :) https://www.macrumors.com/2017/10/24/ios-11-calculator-animation-bug/

Comment: @Drt They all use the same principals, if that helps,

Comment: Is it **only** 3 x 2 = 51 but _not_  2 x 3 = 51?

Comment: One observation is - the first digit of each of the results is **5** (Either it is fixed or it can be sum of left hand side two operands - 2 and 3)

Comment: This is just like normal math, the commutative property is intact: **a • b = b • a**, but **a ÷ b ≠≠ b ÷ a**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> The ASCII code of the number of characters in the written version of the answer. ASCII codes for numbers are in the range [48-57] (for [0-9]).

So

> 2+3 = 5 > FIVE > 4 > 52
>  3*2 = 6 > SIX > 3 > 51
>  2^3 = 8 > EIGHT > 5 > 52
>  3/2 = 1.5 > ONE.FIVE > 3.4 > 51.52
>  7x2 = 14 > FOURTEEN > 8 > 56
>  9+8 = 17 > SEVENTEEN > 9 > 57
>  3-2 = 1 > ONE > 3 > 51
>  3-1 = 2 > TWO > 3 > 51

Comment: Excellent and great to see answering again. Small typo maybe EIGHT > 5

Comment: If this is the answer, sqrt(2-3) should give i, which would be 49. I don't know if that falls afoul of "can't concieve of an answer that would not start with 5"

Comment: Correct, Levieux, and correct as well, @Sconibulus, nice job of [tag:lateral-thinking].

Comment: I figured it was ASCII based, but failed to see the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I think the rule is:

> Calculate the answer: if number 5 append with 2: e.x. 2+3=5 => 52; if number >5 then final answer is 5 appended with the difference of number and 5: e.g. 3*2 =6 => 51 i.e.(5(6-5)); if number <5 then answer 5 appended with number itself e.g 1 is <5 so 51 so 3/2 = 1.5 => 51.52

Answer (score 2):

Could be an infinite number of things, but one is:

> Redefine addition, multiplication, exponentiation and division as $add(a ,b)$, $mul(a, b)$, $exp(a, b)$, and $div(a, b)$ such that (using normal operators on the right-hand-side): 
>  $$ add(a, b) = \frac{(10+a)\cdot(10+b)}{3}$$
>  $$ mul(a, b) = add(a, b) - 1$$
>  $$ exp(a, b) = add(a, b) + 1$$
>  $$ div(a, b) = mul(a, b) + \frac{add(a, b)}{100}$$

Comment: Recursive definition alert: $a+b=\displaystyle\frac{\left(\frac{20\cdot\left(\frac{20\cdot\dots}{3}\right)}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{20\cdot\left(\frac{20\cdot\dots}{3}\right)}{3}\right)}{3}$, and that's not even taking into account multiplication!

Comment: @boboquack hahaha - yeah I was going to state right-hand-sides use normal operators! Guess I'll edit...

Answer (score 1):

I think it follows the following rules

> Subtract 5 and prepend the number 5 to the remainder.  i.e. 8 becomes 53, five, because its remainder is 0, is replaced by a 5

AND

> If the number ends in "5", append 2, so 5 becomes 52 and 1.5 becomes 1.52

Thus

> 2+3 = 5, becomes 5 after the first rule is applied and 52 after the second is applied
> 3x2 = 6 becomes 51 after the first rule is applied, second rule doesn't apply
> 2^3 = 8 becomes 53 after the first rule is applied, second rule doesn't apply
>  3/2 = 1.5, which has a remainder of 1.5, becomes 51.5 after the first rule and 51.52 after the second

Comment: Though that *does* seem to work, that is not the method that I used to derive my answer.